# How to create php array from mysql result, perform calculation, resort array, present results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have a photo website on which I am trying to perform a query against a MySQL database. The query is against a concatenated field of 'title' and 'keyword' called 'title_keyword'.
I want to take the search results and sort them by a newly formed variable called 'sort_priority' which is checking to see if the search word is in the 'title' field. If it is in the 'title' field then I want to assign a value of 1 and if not in the title field then a value of 2. The resulting array will be sorted by 'sort_priority' and output to the screen.

Here is the logic I am using with PHP and MySQL:

1) Query the MySQL database and assign variables. (This works just fine)

2) Take the results, assign each field to a variable, create a new variable that performs a calculation on one of the variables returned

```
$data_array=array();
// get each row
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
//get data
$image_id = "{$row['image_id']}";
$title = "{$row['title']}";
$imageurl = "{$row['imageurl']}";


// Create sort_priority to identify if search word is in title field. 
//If it is then set to 1 to force this higher in the result list after sorting

$sort_priority = 2;
if(stristr($title,$search))
{ $sort_priority = 1;}
```

Everything above this point works. Now for the part I'm stumped on. How to create and add data to the array and then sort on my new $sort_priority variable.

*Here is what I've written but it just doesn't work*******

```
// Create array and sort by title then keyword (tk_sort)
$data_array = array(
'image_id' => $image_id, 
'title' => $title, 
'imageurl' => $imageurl, 
'sort_priority' => $sort_priority);

// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data_array as $key => $row) {
    $image_id[$key]  = $row['image_id'];
    $title[$key] = $row['atitle'];
    $imageurl[$key]  = $row['imageurl'];
    $sort_priority[$key] = $row['sort_priority'];
}

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key

array_multisort($sort_priority, SORT_ASC);

// end of array creation and sort
```

3) Output the newly sorted array to a table

Not sure how to get the data out of it. Do I have to use a loop or something?

Answer (score 0):

You could just let MySQL do the majority of the work. This should work (haven't tried it myself):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', `title`, `keyword`) AS search_term,
IF( INSTR(`search_term`, 'your_search_value_here') > 0, 1, 2 ) AS priority_key,
`image_id`, `imageurl`
FROM table_name_here
ORDER BY `priority_key`;
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks! I used this and had to modify it some to work. Also, the statement would not work with the created search_term field in the IF statement.       Now what I would like to see is if there's a way to have the search value 'your_search_value_here' found in search_term only if it's a full word and not just a string. Any ideas?